# using a function inside a lamba expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

To manage rounding there are usually two methods, the first method is round values then to sum them. Or sum values then to round them. Of course to the required precision that you want.

I want to go with the first method and I need to update this line that currently do the opposite.

```
this.ClonedEntity.MontantHT = ArroundDecimal.CustomDecimalArround(correctedLines.Sum(l => l.MontantHT ?? 0));
```

When I try to call my static method in the lambda expression it doesn't work.

How would you suggest to do it while keeping use of the linq syntax ?

Thank you.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a good error description. Please show what you tried and _what_ didn't work. Did you get any compiler errors -> please show. Did you get exceptions -> please show. Did you get a wrong result -> please show sample data, expected result and received result.

Comment: @RenéVogt thank you I got the syntax from Christos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
this.ClonedEntity.MontantHT = correctedLines
          .Select(x=>ArroundDecimal.CustomDecimalArround(x.MontantHT ?? 0))
          .Sum();
```

Comment: yes I was looking for this. Thank you

Comment: @yass1n3 You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

`something = correctedLines.Sum(l => ArroundDecimal.CustomDecimalArround(l.MontantHT ?? 0))`